# Calculating divergence and curl from optical flow and plotting it

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I'm using **flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback()** to calculate optical flow in a video and it gives me a numpy array with a shape of (height, width, 2) that contains the **Fx** and **Fy** values for each pixel (**flow[:,:,0] = Fx** and **flow[:,:,1] = Fy**).

For calculating the divergence I'm using np.gradient like this:

```
def divergence_npgrad(flow):
    Fx, Fy = flow[:, :, 0], flow[:, :, 1]
    F = [Fx, Fy]
    d = len(F)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(F[i], axis=i) for i in range(d)])
```

Next, I want to calculate the curl. I know there is a curl function in **sympy.physics.vector** but I really don't get how is it working or how is it would apply to my **flow**. So I thought I could use np.gradient for this too. In 2D I need to calculate **dFy/dx - dFx/dy** for every pixel, so i wold be like this:

```
def curl_npgrad(flow):
    Fx, Fy = flow[:, :, 0], flow[:, :, 1]
    dFx_dy = np.gradient(Fx, axis=1)
    dFy_dx = np.gradient(Fy, axis=0)
    curl = np.ufunc.reduce(np.subtract, [dFy_dx, dFx_dy])
    return curl
```

Is it a right way to do this or am I missing something?

Now if I have the **curl**, I want to make two plots with **matplotlib**.
My point is that I want to show the vectors from **flow** with different colormaps.
One plot would use the magnitude values of the vectors as colormap, normalized to (0-magnitude_max).
The other plot would use the **curl** values as colormap, where the arrows are blue if the **curl** is negative and red if the **curl** is positive in that position.

Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
def flow_plot(flow, frame):
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    h, w = flow.shape[:2]
    dpi = 72
    xinch = w / dpi
    yinch = h / dpi

    step = 24

    y, x = np.mgrid[step / ((h % step) // 2):h:step, step / ((w % step) // 2):w:step].reshape(2, -1).astype(int)
    fx, fy = flow[y, x].T
    mag = np.sqrt(np.power(fx, 2) + np.power(fy, 2))
    fx = fx / mag
    fy = fy / mag

    curl = curl_npgrad(flow)
    curl_map = curl[y, x]

    quiver_params = dict(cmap='Oranges', # for magnitude
                         #cmap='seismic', # for curl
                         norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0), # for magnitude
                         #norm = colors.CenteredNorm(), # for curl
                         units='xy',
                         scale=0.03,
                         headwidth=3,
                         headlength=5,
                         minshaft=1.5,
                         pivot='middle')

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(xinch, yinch), dpi=dpi)
    plt.imshow(frame)
    plt.quiver(x, y, fx, fy, mag, **quiver_params)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
    plt.axis('off')
    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    img = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')
    img = img.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
    plt.close(fig)
    return img
```

*I'm converting the plot to a cv2 image so i can use it for opencv video writer.*

I noticed that if I'm not showing the original frame behind the plot, I have to invert the y axis and use **-fy** in **plt.quiver()**, if I want to show the frame behind, I have to invert the y axis too, can use **fy**, but than I have to flip the whole image afterwards. How does it make any sense? I can't get it.

As for the curl, it's kinda messy for me. barely showing any color, random red an blue spots, not a buch of red/blue arrows where the fluid clearly rotating. It's like these:
[image1 of the messy curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXI9C.jpg), [image2 of the messy curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZeHT.jpg)

Is it a bad way to calculate the curl for this kind of flow? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the way you've set up your axes correctly, you're missing a `flow = np.swapaxes(flow, 0, 1)` at the top of both `divergence_npgrad` and `curl_npgrad`.

I tried applying your curl and divergence functions to simple functions where I already knew the correct curl and divergence.

For example, I tried this function:

```
F_x = x
F_y = y
```

Produces this plot:

[image: plot where arrows point out from center]

For this function, divergence should be high everywhere. Applying your function, it tells me that divergence is 0.

Code to produce this array:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,10),np.linspace(-2,2,10))

u = x
v = y
field2 = np.stack((u, v), axis=-1)

plt.quiver(x, y, field2[:, :, 0], field2[:, :, 1])
```

I also tried a function for testing curl:

```
F_x = cos(x + y)
F_y = sin(x - y)
```

Which produces this plot:

[image: plot where arrows circle around center]

Code to produce this array:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,2,10),np.linspace(0,2,10))

u = np.cos(x + y)
v = np.sin(x - y)
field = np.stack((u, v), axis=-1)

plt.quiver(x, y, field[:, :, 0], field[:, :, 1])
```

<sub>Thanks to [U of Mich. Math department for this example](https://instruct.math.lsa.umich.edu/lecturedemos/ma215/docs/16_5/examples.html)!</sub>

For this function, curl should be highest around the center swirl. Applying your curl function to this, I get a result that curl is highest in the corners.

Here's the code I tried which works:

```py
def divergence_npgrad(flow):
    flow = np.swapaxes(flow, 0, 1)
    Fx, Fy = flow[:, :, 0], flow[:, :, 1]
    dFx_dx = np.gradient(Fx, axis=0)
    dFy_dy = np.gradient(Fy, axis=1)
    return dFx_dx + dFy_dy

def curl_npgrad(flow):
    flow = np.swapaxes(flow, 0, 1)
    Fx, Fy = flow[:, :, 0], flow[:, :, 1]
    dFx_dy = np.gradient(Fx, axis=1)
    dFy_dx = np.gradient(Fy, axis=0)
    curl = dFy_dx - dFx_dy
    return curl
```

Some explanation of why I think this is a correct change:

- `np.gradient(..., axis=0)` provides the gradient across rows, because that's axis 0. In your input image, you have the shape (height, width, 2), so axis 0 actually represents height, or y. Using `np.swapaxes(flow, 0, 1)` swaps the order of the x and y axes of that array.
- Using `np.ufunc.reduce` is not required - you can use broadcasting instead and it will work fine. It's also a little easier to read.

Here are the results for using this code.

1. Here is the result of the divergence calculation on the first function.

   [image: a plot of a function of x and y, which is 0.888 everywhere]

   Result: positive, constant value everywhere.
2. Here is the result of the curl calculation on the second function.

   [image: a function which peaks at x=y=pi/4 and declines from there]

   Result: a positive value centered on the swirly part of the function. (There's a change of axes here - 0,0 is in the top left.)

Comment: Wow, silly me. Thank you so much. Now the code does what it supposed to do, the images are showing the right divergence and curl. Just a minor change, since I swapped the axes, instead of using **np.swapaxes()** , I just swap the **axis=0** and **axis=1** parameters inside the **np.gradient()** function so I don't need to coorect it later and I can leave all the rest of my code as it is and for me it's kinda easier to remember my mistake. So thanks again, you saved me from a lot of headache.